# Why is this code failing in c?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, ansi-c

I'm trying to loop a 2D array, but for some reason the statement:

```
var = matrix[i + 1][j] // Fails for i = 1 and j = 0
```

BUT

```
next = i + 1; var = matrix[next][j] // Works, why???..
```

I think it should works because if i equals one and I add 1 it's 2, and I know that value is not empty, at least in my case, oh one thing to mention is that I'm testing with the following inputs: >4 4 1, meaning a 4x4 matrix with 1 rotation, so I am sure for a fact that matrix[2][0] is not empty and I can print it and access to it and all.

Here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


void rotateMatrix(int** matrix, int top, int right, int left, int bottom)
{
//int rows = right;
//int columns = bottom;
int rowScan = 0;

int columnScan = 0;

int high = 0;
int low = 0;
int test = matrix[2][0]; 


for (int i = 0; rowScan != 1;)
{
    for (int j = 0; columnScan != 1;)
    {
        //int next = i + 1;
        high = matrix[i + 1][j]; //FAILS HERE WHEN 
        matrix[i + 1][j] = low != 0 ? low : matrix[i][j];
        i++;

        if (i >= bottom)
        {
            bottom--;
            break;
        }

        if ((i + 1) < bottom)
        {
            low = matrix[i + 1][j];
            matrix[i + 1] = high;
        }

        if ((i + 1) == bottom)
        {
            columnScan = 1;
            rowScan = 1; 
        }

       }
      }
    }



  int main()
 {
//-- Declaring variables
int rows, columns, rotations;

//-- Initializing variables
rows = 0;
columns = 0;
rotations = 0;

//-- Scanning parameters and adding them to the stdin buffer
scanf("%d %d %d", &rows, &columns, &rotations);

//-- Initializing 2D array to save the Matrix values allocating space in memory
int **matrix = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));

//-- Initializing each allocated pointer to each column size
for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));

//-- Scanning Matrix values and saving them into stdin buffer
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
//      scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

//-- Rotating R times
 while ((rotations--) != 0)
    rotateMatrix(matrix, 0, columns, 0, rows); 


for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

getchar(); 
getchar();

return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Please explain what is "fails"?

Comment: Memory Access Violation

Comment: @user3044096 use a debugger to step into your code, find the line that causes the crash, trace the values in the variables and check for anything suspicious.

Comment: I don't see any 2D array...

Comment: For one thing, `matrix[i + 1] = high;` is pretty clearly wrong. On GCC, `x.c:36:27: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

Comment: what is the intent of `int test = matrix[2][0]` regarding the `0`?

Comment: with int test = matrix[2][0] I was just trying to test if it was crashing, I'm using Visual Studio to code this, not sure about what compiler is being used, but it doesn't really throw that exception, and it works for i = 0

Comment: It works for i = 0, so I don't think it's a casting issue, and Tony I debugged and couldn't find anything suspicius, I'm a little new to C here

Comment: If variations in the code which seem to amount to the same thing sometimes work and sometimes not, suspect *undefined behaviour* somewhere.

Comment: I think it might have to do with how you create your 2D array in your driver.  That is an array of pointers to arrays , not necessarily a 2D array, which I believe must be in 1 block of memory.

Comment: I am immediately suspicious when an array of pointers to arrays is described as a '2D' array :(

Comment: To test, make a simple 2D global array and pass that in.

Comment: check Rob's reply. This is a bug in your program, you are overwriting a pointer  with an int value. This causes a memory corruption when you try to access an element from this row next time. Replacing 'i+1' with 'next' probably cause compiler to allocate memory a bit differently and avoid immediate crash, actually masking the bug. You would need to run a memory checker tool (like valgrind on linux) to check for such situations.

Comment: What's the point of variable `j` in your loop nest? You initialize it to 0, but you never thereafter change it.

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. Read the warnings, understand them, fix them, run your program, always in that order.

Comment: Building an array or pointers to arrays, assembled with malloc and then a malloc loop, and then accessing it as if it's a contiguous 2D-array, (which it is NOT), with, say 'matrix[i][j]', is VERY suspicious, no matter if the compiler allows that syntax or not:(

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I was able to find what the issue was, I'm going to answer my own question, thanks!

Comment: Rob was right!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    matrix[i + 1] = high;
```

This line was the issue, I was missing [j], visual studio didn't throw an exception that's why I wasn't able to know what was happening, but using the GCC compiler and checking the warnings helped me find out what I was doing wrong, thanks!